# Memory issues with Core Graphics

Tags: ios, memory-management, memory-leaks, core-graphics, core-animation

I draw a table "by hand", by using primitives of Core Graphics.
The view is re-draw when I click a button.
The problem is that when I profile the code in Instruments, the VM Regions keep increase, while Heap and Anonymous VM oscillate (and I would expect it).

[image]

And the details about CoreAnimation:

[image]

An excerpt of my drawRect:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

    // Drawing code
    CGContextRef context     = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGRect paperRect         = CGRectMake(self.bounds.origin.x+hourLabelSize+self.marginX,
                                           10 +self.cellBorder  ,
                                          self.bounds.size.width,
                                          self.cellHeight * 48
                                          );
    // custom shadow
    drawLinearGradient(context, paperRect, whiteColor.CGColor, lightGrayColor.CGColor);
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGFloat outerMargin = 5.0f;
    CGFloat eventSize;
    // Draw table
    CGRect hourRect;
    CGRect outerRect;
    CGMutablePathRef outerPath;
    CGRect strokeRect;
    CGRect rowRect;
    for (int j=0; j < 7;j++)
    {
    for (int i=0; i < numberOfRows; i++)
    {
        // Odd index means we are in the half of an hour


        if ( (i%2) == 0)
        {
            [hour setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:00",(int)floor(i/2)]];
            // Draw box around hours //
            if (j == 0 && i >0)
            {
                CGContextSaveGState(context);

                hourRect   = CGRectMake(5, i*cellHeight-5, hourLabelSize, 28);
                outerRect  = CGRectInset(hourRect, outerMargin, outerMargin);
                outerPath = newRoundedRectForRect(outerRect, 6.0);
                CGContextAddPath(context, outerPath);
                CFRelease(outerPath); // <--- This solve the leak!!

                // Draw gradient
                strokeRect = CGRectInset(hourRect, 5.0, 5.0);
                CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, boxColor.CGColor);
                CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0);
                CGContextStrokeRect(context, strokeRect);
                drawLinearGradient(context, strokeRect, whiteColor.CGColor, lightGrayColor.CGColor);
                CGContextRestoreGState(context);

            }
        }
        else
        {
            [hour setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:30",(int)floor(i/2)]];

        }

        // Draw hours
        if (j == 0 && i > 0)
            [hour drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, i*cellHeight, hourLabelSize+10, 26) withFont:font lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByClipping alignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
        // Draw row
        CGContextBeginPath(context);
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, boxColor.CGColor);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, self.cellBorder);
        rowRect   = CGRectMake(j*cellWidth + hourLabelSize +self. marginX - self.cellBorder/2, i*cellHeight+10 + self.cellBorder / 2, cellWidth , cellHeight);
        CGContextStrokeRect(context, rowRect);


} //


    CGContextFlush(context);
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

The first thing I do not understand is why I see VM:CoreAnimation. CoreGraphics is part of Core Animation?
Secondly, what I shall watch as syntoms of bad allocation: VM Regions, XCode measurements or  Head and Anonymous?
Regards!

**[EDIT]**

The `createRoundedRect` is as follows

```
CGMutablePathRef newRoundedRectForRect(CGRect rect, CGFloat radius)
{
    CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));
    CGPathAddArcToPoint(path, NULL, CGRectGetMaxX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect), CGRectGetMaxX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect), radius);
    CGPathAddArcToPoint(path, NULL, CGRectGetMaxX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect), CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect), radius);
    CGPathAddArcToPoint(path, NULL, CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect), CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect), radius);
    CGPathAddArcToPoint(path, NULL, CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect), CGRectGetMaxX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect), radius);
    CGPathCloseSubpath(path);


    return path;
}:
```

and the `drawLineGradient.m` :

```
void drawLinearGradient(CGContextRef context, CGRect rect, CGColorRef startColor, CGColorRef endColor)
{
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGFloat locations[] = { 0.0, 1.0 };

    NSArray *colors = @[(__bridge id) startColor, (__bridge id) endColor];

    CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, (__bridge CFArrayRef) colors, locations);

CGPoint startPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));
CGPoint endPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect));

CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextAddRect(context, rect);
CGContextClip(context);
CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, startPoint, endPoint, 0);
CGContextRestoreGState(context);

CGGradientRelease(gradient);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
colors = nil;
```

}

Comment: What does the static analyser tell you? I'd suspect the drawLinearGradient method, since it isn't shown here, also your createRoundedRect...

Comment: See my edited answer, I added some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you see core animation is because all iOS views are layer-backed views. 
The reason for your leak is that you release the path. 
ARC does not manage Core Foundation objects.

Comment: And then? You would say that "I did not release the path"? I edited the question and inserted the complete code. I release the path at the end.

Comment: Also release in newRoundedRectForRect() the memory management rules still apply there.

Comment: How to release the path if I have to return it ?

Comment: @giuseppe: You don't have to, and should not, release it in `newRoundedRectForRect`, although you should rename it to `createRoundedRectPathForRect` to clarify that (a) it returns an ownership, which the caller (`drawRect:`) must release, and (b) it creates a path, not a rect.

Comment: @giuseppe: The alternative would be for `roundedRectPathForRect` to return `CFAutorelease(path)`, and `drawRect:` not to release it. That will only work on iOS 7 or later.

Comment: Ah. Peter, thanks and good points. My intent was ensuring the CGPaths were released properly. The naming conventions are indeed important to understanding and adhering to the memory management. (Except where the docs document exceptions)

Comment: +1 for the mentioning Core Animation appeared in the allocation because of layers